# Cannot receive error from GraphQL with graphql-middleware-sentry

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, prisma

**Note:** The problem was in graphql-middleware-sentry not forwarding on the errors. The solution is below and marked as the correct answer.

I'm currently handling a form using React and Apollo React Hooks on the frontend, and a mixture of GraphQL-Yoga and Prisma on the backend. The mutation works fine, and the form is ok. But I cannot receive errors thrown by the backend in React.

I've tried various error types but I haven't had much luck. For example, my mutation in react looks like this:

```
 const [requestPasswordResetMutation, { data, error, loading }] = useMutation(
    REQUEST_PASSWORD_REQUEST,
    {
      errorPolicy: 'all',
    },
  )
```

On the backend, I might want to throw an error where an email address isn't recognised. I run a simple check such as:

```
if (!user) {
    throw Error('User not found')
  }
```

This error is successfully triggered and picked up by Sentry. But no error is detected by the frontend in the `errors` variable. Instead, the form acts as though it is successfully submitted (given the absence of values in the `errors` object.

Can anyone give me a pointer on how I'm meant to be communicating errors from the backend to the frontend here?

Resolver code:

```
const requestPasswordReset = async (parent, { email }, context) => {
  const user = await context.prisma.user({
    email,
  })

  if (!user) {
    throw new Error('User not found')
  }

  const passwordResetToken = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex')
  const passwordTokenExpiry = expiryDate()

  try {
    await context.prisma.updateUser({
      data: {
        passwordResetToken,
        passwordTokenExpiry,
      },
      where: {
        email: user.email,
      },
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Send email
  }

  return {
    message: 'Reset token sent',
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the error listed in the `errors` array inside the response? You can see the whole response from the server inside the Network tab of your browser's DevTools.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I actually get no response, other than a null value for the message I want to send back. For example, it would normally return `message: 'Reset token sent'`. Instead it returns: `message: null`.

Comment: So you *are* getting a response, just that the `data` property looks like this: `{ "message": null }`. However, the response from the server can also include an `errors` array in addition to the `data` object. So I'm asking if there is an `errors` array in the response and if so, what its contents are. The only way to verify this is by looking at your DevTools.

Comment: Hey, so the response doesn't contain an errors array. The only thing getting returned in the response (looking at the network tab in DevTools) is `{"data":{"requestPasswordReset":null}}`

Comment: Ok. So that's why Apollo is not showing any errors. Somewhere along the line, the error you're throwing inside the resolver is being swallowed up instead of being caught by your GraphQL service. If I had to bet, I'd say you're using a try/catch and not throwing the error again. Please update your question with the code for the resolver in question.

Comment: If you're using something like graphql-middleware, that might also be swallowing the error.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. I've updated my question with the resolver code. Only middlewares I'm using are the sentry error handler, and graphql-shield.

Comment: This looks as though it's the sentry middleware which is swallowing the error!

Comment: Yup, I posted an answer. It might be helpful to update the question body and title to reflect the true issue -- something like "Cannot receive error from GraphQL with graphql-middleware-sentry". That might help folks having the same issue find your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`graphql-middleware-sentry` has a `forwardErrors` parameter that is `false` by default. You should set it to `true` in order to prevent it from swallowing the errors you throw:

```
const sentryMiddleware = sentry({
  forwardErrors: true,
  ...
})
```